# compare first cell with other values of row and count matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have following `DataFrame`:

```
key id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
1   8   1   1   9   7   
2   5   2   2   2   2
3   5   4   7   9   1
```

I would like to count the number of times the values of **id1-5** match with my **key** value and safe it as new column.

This would be my desired result:

```
key id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 matches
1   8   1   1   1   7   3
2   5   2   2   2   2   4
3   5   4   7   9   1   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df['new'] = df.eq(df.key,axis=0).sum(axis=1)-1
df
Out[108]: 
   key  id1  id2  id3  id4  id5  new
0    1    8    1    1    9    7    2
1    2    5    2    2    2    2    4
2    3    5    4    7    9    3    1
```

Comment: is something similar with a `df[df.key == ...]` filter?

Comment: @anon01 what you mean filter here :-)

Comment: ignore filter.  Can this be done with `df[df.key == ...]` inplace of `.eq`?

Comment: @anon01 nope , since eq need also pass the axis=0, if only do `==` this is will return something else

Comment: I like your answer more because it is not dependent on column names. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.filter` with `eq`:

```
df["matches"] = df.filter(like="id").eq(df["key"], axis=0).sum(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   key  id1  id2  id3  id4  id5  matches
0    1    8    1    1    1    7        3
1    2    5    2    2    2    2        4
2    3    5    4    7    9    1        0
```

Comment: that's cool - still getting used to the `.fitler`, `.eq` syntax.  Any idea how these methods compare with apply or raw numpy performance-wise?

Comment: @anon01 While all three have different characteristics, if one were to do the same job, I would say `eq` should be lot faster than `apply` in general, and slightly slower than `numpy` due to some overhead.